# Icerting cell content into formula

Tags: google-sheets

I need to take column A and in column C insert the content of column "A" into Cell C formula

So Looks like this 
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPg7W.png)

I would just put the A1 or A2 in there but for some reason its not picking up the locations but does by name.

So I need a script/formula that will insert the content of cell A into the formula between the " "

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(E:O,A3)
```

works fine here.